# Why empty list return size 1 in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a doubt why this dart code is behaving this way:

```
List<String> a = ''.split(';');
print(a); // prints []
print(a.length); // prints 1
print(a.isEmpty); prints false
```

If 'a' is an empty list, why it has size 1 and why '.isEmpty' returns false??

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's not empty.  It *looks* empty when printed because it contains an empty string as its sole element.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is described exactly in the documentation of Dart, inside the [`split()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/String/split.html) method, you would find this part:

```
// If this string is empty, the result is an empty list if pattern matches
// the empty string, and it is [""] if the pattern doesn't match.

var string = '';
string.split('');                       // []
string.split("a");                      // ['']
```

Good Luck.